# How do I get the date of the last day of the previous month in the previous year in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am writing a query with a where clause which needs to return the final day of the previous month in the previous year. So if I ran it today (`18/06/2014`), it would return `31/05/2013`. If I ran it next month on `19/07/2014` it would return `30/06/2013` and so on.

I can use

```
select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEadd(MONTH,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

which returns the final date of last month but I can't work out how to adapt this to give me the date a year previously.

I can add - 365 to the end of the above code which does what I want but wouldn't account for leap years. Although I don't expect my reports to be in use for long enough for this to necessarily matter it would be good to find a solution that works nicely (and to think that they might be).

Any solutions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add another `dateadd(YY, -1, {your code})` around your `getdate()` to roll the year back first, then look to previous month (per comments below).

```
select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEadd(MONTH,datediff(month,0,DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE())),0))
```

Comment: You should reorder the dateadds and do the year first. Otherwise it will give Feb 28th instead of 29th when the previous year was a leap year.